# AWK | Dynamic row to column conversion

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

My Files:

```
EventTime=20180726001317
ObjectOfReference=TCU_XXX202
SPtext=Heartbeat Failure
EAName=TCU_XXX202
EventTime=20180726001317
ObjectOfReference=TCU_XXX203
SPtext=Heartbeat Failure
EAName=TCU_XXX203
```

Expected Output:

```
EventTime;ObjectOfReference;SPtext;EAName
20180726001317;TCU_XXX202;Heartbeat Failure;TCU_XXX202
20180726001317;TCU_XXX203;Heartbeat Failure;TCU_XXX203
```

I tried with awk script but it's not working:

```
awk -F\"= :\" '!/%a/&&/-EventTime|EAName|-ObjectOfReference|-SPtext|%A/{if(\$1 != \"%A\")printf \$NF\",\";else print \"\\n\"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F= '{a=(FNR!=NR)+1;printf "%s"(NR%4==0?RS:";"),$a} a==1&&NR>=4{nextfile}' file file
```

However if you don't need the header line, this will also do the job (and work with `mawk` too):

```
awk -F= '{printf "%s"(NR%4==0?RS:";"),$2}' file
```

---

Explanation:

- `-F=` sets the field separator to `=`.
- `a=(FNR!=NR)+1`: `$a` is set to `1` in the first file and `2` in the second one.
- `printf "%s"(NR%4==0?RS:";"),$a`: print the string and if it's a 4th line print the row separator `RS`, else print the field separator `;`
- `a==1&&NR>=4`: if we are in the first file and 4 lines are processed ...
- `nextfile` ... start processing the next file (this is GNU specific)

---

Output:

```
EventTime;ObjectOfReference;SPtext;EAName
20180726001317;TCU_XXX202;Heartbeat Failure;TCU_XXX202
20180726001317;TCU_XXX203;Heartbeat Failure;TCU_XXX203
```